# Read from multiple event logs in Eventuate

Tags: scala, akka, event-sourcing

I'm playing with some event sourcing things, to get a feel for it. The next thing I want to try is [Eventuate](https://github.com/RBMHTechnology/eventuate). It looks very good, but from what I could gather from the documentation, any EventsourcedActor (and the View, Processor variants, etc) can only read from and write to a single event log.

So for example I have a `User` event log, with `EventsourcedActor`s for each user of the system. These would get commands like `CreateUser`, `ChangePassword` or `DeleteUser` and emit events like `UserCreated` etc.

Now suppose this is a forum application, and once a user deletes their account, existing posts from that user should be deleted or marked in some other way.

How would I do that? I would instinctively have a separate event log for forum threads/posts, but in that case I don't see how the actors dealing with those would be able to listen for an event like `UserDeleted`.

Do I really need one gigantic event log for the whole application? Or can I make an actor read from more than one event log?

I've seen `EventsourcedProcessor` which can read from one event log and write to another. It seems a bit odd to use that as a "bridge" simply to get events from one log to another.

What I would intuitively want is to have the aggregate/actor for any given forum post listen to a `UserDeleted` event and then modify its state accordingly.

But given all this, I'm not sure whether I'm completely going the wrong way here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a `Users` event log and a `ForumPosts` event log, it’s actually quite reasonable to use an `EventsourcedProcessor` that consumes `UserDeleted` events from the `Users` event log and writes them (optionally transformed) to the `ForumPosts` event log.

Whenever `EventsourcedActor`s that represent a user’s forum posts are activated they consume the `UserDeleted` event and and change their internal state to *deleted*, for example. Compared to the *process manager* approach described in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37616263/263264), it has the advantage that forum post actors don’t need to be alive for processing commands from the process manager which is especially useful when you have thousands or millions of these actors. With [event-driven communication](http://rbmhtechnology.github.io/eventuate/architecture.html#event-driven-communication) you have additional decoupling in time.

Should you still want to follow a *process manager* approach you can use [confirmed delivery](http://rbmhtechnology.github.io/eventuate/reference/event-sourcing.html#reliable-delivery) to reliably deliver process manager commands to receivers, combined with idempotent command processing in the command handler of the forum post actors. On the other hand, with event-driven communication, as explained in the previous paragraph, you don’t need to care about idempotency in the event handler as `EventsourcedProcessor`s are idempotent producers i.e. you’ll never see a `UserDeleted` duplicate in the `ForumPosts` event log.

Answer (score 1):

> It looks very good, but from what I could gather from the documentation, any EventsourcedActor (and the View, Processor variants, etc) can only read from and write to a single event log.

Sounds like each EventsourcedActor is expected to be an Aggregate.  That's pretty reasonable.

> Now suppose this is a forum application, and once a user deletes their account, existing posts from that user should be deleted or marked in some other way.
>
> How would I do that? I would instinctively have a separate event log for forum threads/posts, but in that case I don't see how the actors dealing with those would be able to listen for an event like UserDeleted.
>
> Do I really need one gigantic event log for the whole application? Or can I make an actor read from more than one event log?

The usual idiom for this goes by the name of "process manager".  The basic idea is that you have a very simple event handler listening for changes written by the EventsourcedActors.  When the UserDeleted event appears, the process manager responds by sending ArchivePost commands to the EventsourcedActors that maintain the post histories.

Basically, process managers are glorified state machines; "when I have seen events A, B, and C, then I should schedule command D".  In the examples I have seen, the scheduling is asynchronous -- that is to say, it runs on a different thread than the event handler.

All of the responsibility for changing the model; which is to say, the responsibility for maintaining the integrity of the book of record, belongs to the EventsourcedActors.  Coordinating those changes -- making sure the right commands get sent to the right actors, that's what the state machines do.

*None of the above is specific to Eventuate.*  It's pretty common for event sourced solutions to get to the point where they need to start thinking about coordination, and this is where they usually end up.

Since you usually want the processes to remember where they are on restart, the processes themselves are likely to be event sourced.  Turtles all the way down.

Comment: So the idea is that aggregates are not expected to react to events from "elsewhere", but should rather have an intermediate actor produce a command based on those events from elsewhere? I think I understand the setup you describe, but it feels odd to me. How does this work on replay of the event log?

Comment: ...and just upon typing that, I think I realize where I was going wrong. No matter whether I have an actor reacting to "events" from elsewhere or whether i have the intermediate actor (your state machine) - I need to ensure nothing bad happens on replay anyway. In your case the commands shouldn't be generated again. In my hypothetical case I was misusing the external events as pseudo-commands, so that is basically equivalent. Now I just need to figure out how to handle that.

Comment: Keyword: "Idempotent" -- if your message handling becomes idempotent, lots of tasks become a lot simpler.